# How to update or edit oracle mobile app designer data source in OBIEE12C?

Tags: obiee, bi-publisher

I have a question about editing or updating oracle mobile app designer data source. 
How many ways are there to edit or update its data source?
My app's data source type is bi publisher data model in OBIEE12c and the only way which I know to update or edit the data source is through update icon on the data source pane in the app designer workspace.
Are there another ways to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 11g before there was a button, the only way to update was:

1. Add the following line manually in repository/Admin/Configuration/xmlp-server-config.xml:

```html
<property name="BVCACHE_ALLOW_LOADING_MANUALLY" value="true"/>
```

2. Restart the BI MAD application.
3. Access /io/generate-businessview-cache?cleanup=true from browser. If it runs in localhost, the URL should be like;

http://localhost:9704/mobile/io/generate-businessview-cache?cleanup=true

If it returns a blank page, that means the cache is cleared.

4. Test your app again.